# What is the backbone @$el exactly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views

in many tutorials I see that people do this:

```
view = new Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex(collection: @collection)
$('body').html(view.render().el)
```

And then in the view of EntriesIndex he does:

```
render: ->
  @$el.html(@template())
```

I thought that with `@$el` it was say: hey render this template in the parent element(in this case it's body)...but it doesn't work and not show anything...If I use `$('body').html(@template())` instead all works fine.
Now...why people use `@$el` in tutorials(I've seen this in 2-3 tutorials) ?

Comment: `@$el = $(this.el)`, more or less.

Comment: Ok but why in tutorials they use in this way ? like if this.el is $('body')...instead it's a simple div tag by default...

Comment: As far as I know, in backbone there's absolutely nothing wrong with the idea of attaching a view to an existing DOM node, and there is no absolute right way to render the views either. Do what works, that's the beauty of Backbone: it is flexible and will meet your needs but then again to me the bit unsettling factor about starting from scratch on a flexible, unopinionated framework like backbone, is the lack of "the one true way" to do various things. So when I do it a way that seems to make sense, I am left with that wondering feeling, like is this how I'm supposed to do it?

Comment: @chridam yes but I wanted only understand why in many tutorials they do something that doesn't work...

Comment: Oh, does it show any errors in console like `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html'`?

Answer (score 4):

In Backbone, views usually store a reference to their element, wrapped in jQuery. This is usually named `this.$el`.

The `$` sign indicates that this is not simply a DOM Element, but a full flegded `jQuery` instance. This means you can call methods like `$el.find()` and `$el.children()`.

In CoffeeScript, `@` is a shortcut for `this`. So `@$el` means precisely `this.$el`.